# Why ports added to firewall are still closed?

Tags: firewall

I have added ports 25 and 80 to the firewall and enabled the firewall but even after reboot when I check the ports, they are still closed?
What else do I have to do?
Warmest regards

Comment: Is anything listening on those ports?

Comment: Please edit your question and add more information. What distro and version of Linux are you running? Which firewall application are you running? Is this a virtual machine, a cloud instance, or a desktop or server running on bare metal in a home or work environment?